# Return structure field value from criteria

Tags: matlab, field, structure

I have a MATLAB structure created by `regionprops()` that returns the Area and Centroid of a binary image. At the moment, the structure has 16 pairs of values (an Area and Centroid pair for each binary blob present).
My question is, how can I return the Centroid value where the Area meets a criteria? As in, return the Centroid values for the largest Area.

At the moment, I find the largest Area value via

```
maxArea = max([struct.Area]);
```

which returns the row number of where the max Area is within the structure `struct`. How can I use this row number to output the Centroid value that is the pair for max Area? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[maxArea, ind] = max([s.Area]); %//get the max Area, and the index
s(ind).Centroid %//the centroid with the max area
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks